# Rectilinear motion with constant acceleration in special relativity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, acceleration

> Assume that we have a particle with rest mass $m_0$ that is subject to an acceleration in its instantaneous frame of reference $\overrightarrow{a_0} = a \overrightarrow{e_x},$ with initial conidition $\overrightarrow{r} = \overrightarrow{v} = 0$ at $t = 0$ in the rest frame of reference $S$, where $\overrightarrow{r}$ is the position and $\overrightarrow{v}$ is the velocity. How can we determine the acceleration $4-$vector $A^\alpha$ and the $x,y$ and $z$ coordinates of the acceleration in the frame of reference $S$ in terms of $a, m_0$ and $c$?

I don't know how to even start this question. I think this exercise is solved by a very simple idea, but I just can't come up with it.